# How do I deserialise a JSON object to a C# class that uses derived classes?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following classes which I am serialising and deserialising to and from JSON using [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/):

```
public class Message
{
  public Guid MessageId { get; set; }
  public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
  public int TaskId { get; set; }
}

public SomeTask : Task
{
  public string SomeTaskThing { get; set; }
  public List<string> Operations { get; set; }
}

public OtherTask : Task
{
  public int OtherTaskThing { get; set; }
  public List<int> MoreOtherTaskThings { get; set; }
}
```

A `Message` basically consists of a list of `SomeTask` and `OtherTask` `Task`s which I pass across the wire to a message processor that also knows about these classes.

When I serialise a `Message` I do the following:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        message, 
        Formatting.Indented, 
        new JsonSerializerSettings
          {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
          });
```

My derived classes are serialised as I would expect along with `$type` names embedded in the JSON.

However when I deserialise the JSON string back to a `Message` object the deserialiser doesn't rehydrate my derived class objects. I just get a list of the base class `Task`.

I thought `$type` added to the JSON string by using `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects` might have provided a hint to the deserialiser about which classes to instantiate, but I was wrong.

What do I need to do to deserialise objects who's base class is `Task` and rehydrate the derived classes into the `List<Task>`?

I'm limited to .NET Framework 3.5 for this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are using the same `JsonSerializerSettings` to deserialize as well. It doesn't have to be the same instance but it must have `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects` set in order to work on deserialization.

Comment: Ah...that completely hit my blindspot. Thanks.